# How to generate random number that satisfying poisson distribution

Tags: algorithm, matlab, statistics, probability

I want to generate 500000 random numbers of Poisson distribution with `lambda = 1`, and `T=6` by using the composition method which can be describes as follows:

1. Generate uniform r.v. `z1`, `z2`, …
2. Stop when `z1.z2..zm<=exp(-lamda*T)`
3. Assign `k = m – 1`

Then count how many number in each of 10 intervals (`[0,1]`,`[2,3]`,…, `[16,17]`, `[18,∞)`].

I know that MATLAB has a built-in function `poissrnd` for above task. However, I want to use the above algorithm to do it by myself. I tried do it and compared it with the result of the `poissrnd` function, but my code gives a wrong result. Could you look at my code and give me some comments?

```
num_generated = 500000;
lambda=1;T=6;
k_vec=[]; %% Store k
for i=1:number_generated
    multiple=1;
    for j=1:number_generated
        %% Step 1: Generate uniform in the interval [0,1]: z1,z2...
        z=rand(); 
        %% Step 2: Stop when z1z2...zm<=exp(-lambda*T)
        multiple=multiple*z;
        if(multiple<=exp(-lambda*T))
            k=j-1;
            k_vec=[k_vec k]; % Record k in vec
            break;
        end
    end
end
range_1 = sum( k_vec(:)==0 )+sum(k_vec(:)==1) % # number with in range [0,1]
range_2 = sum( k_vec(:)==2 )+sum( k_vec(:)==3) % # number with in range [2,3]
range_3 = sum( k_vec(:)==4 )+sum( k_vec(:)==5) % # number with in range [4,5]
range_4 = sum( k_vec(:)==6 )+sum( k_vec(:)==7) % # number with in range [6,7]
range_5 = sum( k_vec(:)==8 )+sum( k_vec(:)==9) % # number with in range [8,9]
range_6 = sum( k_vec(:)==10 )+sum( k_vec(:)==11) % # number with in range [10,11]
range_7 = sum( k_vec(:)==12 )+sum( k_vec(:)==13) % # number with in range [12,13]
range_8 = sum( k_vec(:)==14 )+sum( k_vec(:)==15) % # number with in range [14,15]
range_9 = sum( k_vec(:)==16 )+sum( k_vec(:)==17) % # number with in range [16,17]
range_10 = sum(k_vec(:)>=18)         % # number with in range [18,+infty)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know how many random values it will take for `multiple` to converge, so you need to change your `for` loop over `j` to a while loop that continues as long as `multiple > exp(-lambda*T)`.

By changing this to a `while` loop, you now need `k` to be a counter and to increment it on each iteration of the loop:

(Warning: Untested Code)

```
for i = 1:number_generated
    multiple = 1;
    k = 0;   %// Initialize counter for each number generated
    while multiple > exp(-lambda*T)   %// replace `for` loop
        k = k + 1;    %// Increment counter
        %% Step 1: Generate uniform in the interval [0,1]: z1,z2...
        z = rand(); 
        %% Step 2: Stop when z1z2...zm<=exp(-lambda*T)
        multiple = multiple*z;
    end
    %// If we exit the loop, we know multiple <= exp(-lambda*T)
    k = k - 1;
    k_vec = [k_vec k]; % Record k in vec
end
```

You should also avoid **at all costs** using sequential variable names like `range_1`, `range_2`, ... Matlab is designed to handle arrays and matrices, so you should used them. The simplest way to do this in your case, without even looping or vectorization, is:

```
range(1) = sum(...
range(2) = sum(...
...
range(10) = sum(...
```

Now you have one variable in your workspace rather than 10 and any operations you perform on this variable will be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Matlab so I can't give you the exact syntax for a fix.  At a minimum, it looks like you're forgetting to reset `multiple` and `k` for each new Poisson.  Also, you're only generating a single `z`.

A working implementation to get `num_generated` Poisson outcomes should look something like the following pseudocode:

```
threshold = Math.exp(-lambda * T)
loop num_generated times {
    %% Each time through this loop produces a single Poisson outcome 
    count = 0
    product = 1.0
    while (product = product * rand()) >= threshold {
      count += 1
    }
    %% count now has a valid Poisson value, do what you want with it
}
```